# 3D: rotate a div box in CSS

Tags: css

I am trying achieve a movie-seat-booking project. a div box named screen that is as big movie screen in cinema.

How to achieve that my screen look same as the screen of example. thank you

[image: the example]

```
/*this is my code*/
/*<div class="screen"></div>*/
.screen{
  width: 180px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: .3125rem;
  margin-left: 70px;
  /* X-axis - counter-clockwise. */
  transform: rotateX(-20deg);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}
```

[image: this is what I made]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) css property.Setting the property on a parent container gives its children a 3D space.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.square {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  transform: rotateX(320deg);
  background: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="square"></div>
 </div>
```